# How can i set one property to all ViewControllers with one button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have 12 ViewControllers in my app i create one button in one ViewController, with that button how can i change all the background colour of all 12 ViewControllers. (for example if i set blue background then i want all view controllers with blue background)

Comment: What have you done so far to do this?

Comment: You don't set the background color, you set *some* color - and every viewController has to use that color when being displayed.

Comment: UIAppearanceProxy to the Rescue!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use case for NSNotifications. Have each of your view controllers register in viewDidLoad as a listener for your custom notification key and then when your button is tapped post the notification for all the listeners to update the background colour. Make sure you remove the listener in dealloc or deinit for swift. If all your view controllers inherit from the same superclass you could implement this once in an abstract view controller class and have your 12 view controllers inherit from this.